# I want a windows mail reader that gives me prioritized folders across all my imap accounts

Tags: email-client

I am looking a mail reader that runs on windows7 and gives me a Group buffer very similar to gnus. Where I can order the groups easily and hide all groups below a certain priority.

[Gnus on windows is broken](https://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/950006ccf37760c0?pli=1) so that is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mozilla Thunderbird you would be able to get towards your goal by creating a numbers of "saved search" folders (From File->New->Saved Search)

The virtual "saved search" folders can run a set of defined search rules over any set of real mail folders (even across different e-mail accounts) that you wish.

Unfortunately it does not solve being able to pick the order that these are displayed in.